# add element on select document

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make WYSIWYG like Stackoverflow editor. it can add element block like `<b><i>` by click event in select text.

the currently my code look like this

**HTML**

```
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Bold">
<div id="ctn" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var ctn = document.getElementById('ctn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
ctn.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}, false);

</script>
```

Why it doesn't work? but the below code is work. its old style JavaScript. the code is show as this.

*HTML*

```
 <div contenteditable="true" onclick="SetToBold ();">Select a part of this text!</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
<script>

function SetToBold () {
            document.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
        }

</script>
```

nb:answer it on JavaScript not JQuery. thank you for reading :)

Comment: Can you fiddle your code please ?

Comment: The code you've provided throws: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execCommand' of undefined"*, which means your `ctn` variable has no `document` property.

Comment: You button is a submit. `preventDefault()` needs to be added. Alternatively you can use `<button>` or change the `<input>` type to _BUTTON_.

Comment: #bobthyasian nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting a div element (ctn), but then trying to access it's `document` property. Div elements do not have a `document` property.

#### Edit

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/danwellman/59copttn/) is a working fiddle - select part of the text that says 'make me bold!' and then click the button. It will be bold. The fiddle contains the following JavaScript:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}, false);
```

The *only* difference between your code and the fiddle is that I am calling execCommand on the document object, not selecting the div and trying to access its document property (which it doesn't have)

Comment: i don't know what are you explain for but the below code is say. div have document property cause its work. i just want to use addeventlistener like usual ways to convert old style to modern style. but old style is work but modern style is not work. how can it be?

Comment: FYI: If you want to convert to modern, convert to jQuery.

Comment: #bothyasian i want to know the base of javascript. so i can custom to make application as my wish. what should i comment about JQuery. JQuery size is bigger and more bigger, day by day. there're many function that i even don't need. i can make custom library like JQuery too. how can a site just load a JQuery min 100KB? it will slow down load page for slow connection user.